# Filter list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to rewrite code from Haskell to Prolog.

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count x = length . filter (x==)

f :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
f [] = []
f list = filter (\x -> count x list == 1) list
```

This code return list that contains elements that appears only once in the list.
So if I have list `[1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5]` this function returns `[3,5]`
I tried to find filter construction in Prolog but seems there no such thing. How can I make similar function in Prolog ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the existing answers, I would like to add an answer that is quite **general** in the sense that you can use it in *multiple directions*.

## Building block: `list_element_number/3`

I start with the following predicate, defining a **relation** between:

- a *list* `Ls0`
- an *element* `E`
- the *number* `N` of occurrences of `E` in `Ls0`

Here it is:

```
list_element_number(Ls0, E, N) :-
        tfilter(=(E), Ls0, Ls),
        length(Ls, N).
```

This solution uses `tfilter/3` from [**`library(reif)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl). The predicate *subsumes* the function `count` you have posted. The main benefit of this predicate over the function is that the predicate can be used not only in those cases that even Haskell can do easily, such as:

```
?- list_element_number([a,b,c], a, N).
N = 1.
```

No, we can use it also in *other* directions, such as:

```
?- list_element_number([a,b,c], X, 1).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
false.
```

Or even:

```
?- list_element_number([a,b,E], X, 2).
E = X, X = a ;
E = X, X = b ;
false.
```

Or even:

```
?- list_element_number([A,B,C], X, 3).
A = B, B = C, C = X ;
false.
```

And even in the **most general case**, in which *all* arguments are fresh variables:

```
?- list_element_number(Ls, E, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [E, E],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [E, E, E],
N = 3 .
```

We can *fairly* enumerate all answers like this:

```
?- length(Ls, _), list_element_number(Ls, E, N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_160],
N = 0,
dif(E, _160) ;
Ls = [E, E],
N = 2 .
```

## Main predicate: `list_singletons/2`

Using this building block, we can define `list_singletons/2` as follows:

```
list_singletons(Ls, Singles) :-
        tfilter(count_one(Ls), Ls, Singles).

count_one(Ls, E, T) :-
        list_element_number(Ls, E, Num),
        cond_t(Num=1, true, T).
```

This uses `cond_t/3` and (again) `tfilter/3` from `library(reif)`.

## Sample queries

Here are a few sample queries. First, the test case you have posted:

```
?- list_singletons([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5], Singles).
Singles = [3, 5].
```

It works as desired.

Now a case involving *variables*:

```
?- list_singletons([A,B], Singles).
A = B,
Singles = [] ;
Singles = [A, B],
dif(A, B).
```

On backtracking, all possibilities are *generated*: *Either* `A = B` holds, and in that case, there is *no* element that occurs only once. *Or* `A` is *different* from `B`, and in that case both `A` and `B` occur exactly once.

As a special case of the above query, we can post:

```
?- list_singletons([A,A], Singles).
Singles = [].
```

And as a *generalization*, we can post:

```
?- length(Ls, _), list_singletons(Ls, Singles).
Ls = Singles, Singles = [] ;
Ls = Singles, Singles = [_7216] ;
Ls = [_7216, _7216],
Singles = [] ;
Ls = Singles, Singles = [_7828, _7834],
dif(_7828, _7834) ;
Ls = [_7216, _7216, _7216],
Singles = [] ;
Ls = [_7910, _7910, _7922],
Singles = [_7922],
dif(_7910, _7922) .
```

Enjoy the generality of this relation, obtained via [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

Answer (score 3):

A more simple version :

```
filter_list(L,OutList):-findall(X, (select(X,L, L1),\+member(X, L1)) , OutList).

?- filter_list([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5],L).
L = [3, 5].
```

Without findall, you can try

```
filter_list(In, Out) :- filter_list(In, _, Out).

filter_list([], [], []).

filter_list([H|T], L1, L2) :-
             filter_list(T, LL1, LL2),
             (   member(H, LL1)
             ->  L1 = LL1, L2 = LL2
             ;   (select(H, LL2, L2)
                 ->  L1 = [H|LL1]
                 ;   L1 = LL1, L2 = [H|LL2])).
```

Comment: `filter_list([a,X],[a,b]).` fails yet `X = b, filter_list([a,X], [a,b]).` succeeds

Comment: Yes first version fails but second version succeeds.

Comment: 2nd version succeeds for `filter_list([a,a],[a,a])` **and** `filter_list([a,a],[]).` which is the real one?

Answer (score 2):

A simple version:

(see the comment by @false below, the version with `findall/3` has some inconsistency problems in more complex queries but second version looks ok  however it is definitely not so efficient ).

```
filter_list(L,OutList):-findall(X, (member(X,L),count(X,L,N),N=:=1) , OutList).

count(_,[],0).
count(X,[X|T],N):-count(X,T,N1),N is N1+1.
count(X,[X1|T],N):-dif(X,X1),count(X,T,N).
```

The predicate `filter_list/2` uses `findall/3` and simply states find all X that belong to the list L and count returns 1 and store them in OutList.

Example:

```
?- filter_list([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5],L).
L = [3, 5].
```

You could write `filter_list/2` without using `findall/3` like:

```
filter_list(L,OutList):- filter_list(L,OutList,L).
filter_list([],[],_).
filter_list([H|T],[H|T1],L):-count(H,L,N), N=:=1, filter_list(T,T1,L).
filter_list([H|T],T1,L):-count(H,L,N), N > 1, filter_list(T,T1,L).
```

Comment: `filter_list([a,X], Xs),X = a.` succeeds, yet `X = a, filter_list([a,X], Xs)` fails.

Comment: @false, second version looks ok, so I edited the answer and included an notice about that...

Answer (score 2):

without counting...

```
filter_uniques([],[]).
filter_uniques([H|T],F) :-
    delete(T,H,D),
    ( D=T -> F=[H|R],S=T ; F=R,S=D ),
    filter_uniques(S,R).
```

a more direct rewrite of your code, with library(yall) support for inlining of the filter predicate (the first argument to include/3)

```
filt_uniq(L,F) :-
    include({L}/[E]>>aggregate(count,member(E,L),1),L,F).
```

Comment: `filt_uniq([a,X],[]).` fails incorrectly. Expected: `X = a` or instantiation error.

Comment: @false: thanks... I'm not so much interested... so please forgive me for not 'correcting' the code. In my POV, there is nothing to correct... The test to guard against unwanted instantiation patterns (similar to what you proposed for dif/2 ISO compatibility) should precede this

Comment: Then you should indicate in your answer when your solution works.

Comment: Generally, I target only OP's provided test cases... but I'm curious about **why** I should feel obliged to do what you require... isn't this totally freely provided code ? Just a - potentially large - set of individual viewpoints.... I'm sure we know each other from so many time now... you for sure know I have my ideas about SW

Comment: @false: some days ago, you posed a similar 'problem' about another 'one-liner' I proposed for a different task. I solved the problem -IMHO- in a rather elegant and efficient way, and your only reaction have been a stereotyped - more or less - 'CLP doesn't work with aggregate', without noticing it *does*, for the very problem you posed. I'm more interested in technical points, so maybe you could better support your viewpoint the next time... in particular, mixing constraints and bagof style aggregation  is **very** interesting right now

Comment: If you believe that one or more comments are not appropriate, please do react at the very place! I have seen quite a lot of (to my knowledge) incorrect uses of aggregates plus constraints, lately.

Comment: `bagof/3` does not work together with constraints. Definitely so. Please @-me at a case where you think it does.